# Sort partial vector using STL

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, stdvector

I have a vector of pointers to an array, `vector<float*> points`. The array is of length `d`. I want to sort this vector `points[i]` position to `points[j]` position (inclusive or exclusive, doesn't matter since we can always adjust by 1 accordingly). Further, I want it to be sorted according to `0 <= x < d` th entry. I don't care how the ties are resolved (that is, no tie breaking or sorted wrt `(x+1)%d`th entry -- doesn't matter). Is there any function in C++ for this? I know I can most likely do the `x-th` axis thing by defining my own comparator function for this, but sorting only a section of the vector is the main thing. I didn't find anything relevant to it ([partial_sort()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdpartial_sort-in-cpp/) comes close, but isn't exactly what I want), so I'm sorry if this question has been asked before. Any help would be great. Thanks...

Comment: Sort by what? The contents of the arrays?

Comment: You should show us an example of values and how you expet the to be sorted.

Comment: First, it is a terrible idea to use `std::vector<float*>` in general - there are very few cases when it has use and all are odd and rare - in most cases it is better to use either `std::vector<size_t>` if you want to remember the location of the data or use `std::vector<float>` if you want the data itself. For example I couldn't tell from your question - do your want to sort according to their memory address or their values? Simple sort without non-trivial comparison operators would sort the pointers according to their memory address - do you really want that?

Comment: @ALX23z _"`std::vector<size_t>` if you want to remember the location of the data"_. Huh?

Comment: @Timo - you have another array of floats and you want indices. Is it hard to understand?

Comment: @ALX23z well then you'd need an array of arrays in both cases.

Comment: *extension to the previous comment: or perhaps you want to sort the data the pointers reference to? This a troublesome operation in general- and it is better performed by copying the data into `std::vector<float>` sorting it by native sort, then copying the result into original data. Other approaches are error prone and slow.

Comment: @Timo I don't understand why or what are you talking about but never mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) and pass it iterator range you want to have sorted like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ 2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 2 };

    std::sort(v.begin(), std::min(v.begin() + 3, v.end()));

    for (auto const i : v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And now the output would be:

```
1 2 4 6 5 7 2
```

so only first 3 elements are sorted.

Please, take a closer look at `std::min(v.begin() + 3, v.end())`. This guards you against the end not being past `v.end()`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:13),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cint%3E+v%7B+2,+4,+1,+6,+5,+7,+2+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++std::sort(v.begin(),+std::min(v.begin()+%2B+3,+v.end()))%3B%0A%0A++++for+(auto+const+i+:+v)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+i+%3C%3C+%22+%22%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.637075718015666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:37.5,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.362924281984334,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

**UPDATE**

As proposed by [@Timo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6205379/timo), instead of `std::min(v.begin() + 3, v.end())`, it is better to use `std::next(v.begin(), std::min(static_cast<size_t>(3), v.size()))` so the full code would then be:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ 2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 2 };

    std::sort(v.begin(), std::next(v.begin(), std::min(static_cast<size_t>(3), v.size())));

    for (auto const i : v) {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would probably want to guard against the end not being past `v.end()`; `std::min(v.begin() + 3, v.end())`.`std::min` should do the right thing here, but there is the potential that it won't for some strange containers.

Comment: @Clearer ofc, i was just editing my answer with this

Comment: I wouldn't rely on `std::min` here. If `it + x` goes beyond the end iterator, the result isn't a valid iterator to be used in comparison.

Comment: I'd use `next(v.begin(), std::min(3, v.size())`

Comment: @Timo sounds much much better. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer of @NutCracker:

you can sort only ranges of the container like so:

`std::sort(container.begin() + startIndex, container.begin() + endIndex);`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @NutCracker's answer and whether someone is interested, here is a solution using Range-v3:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <range/v3/action/sort.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/drop.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/take.hpp>

int main() {
    using namespace ranges;
    std::vector<int> v{ 2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 7, 2 };
    v | views::drop(1) | views::take(5) | actions::sort;
    std::cout << views::all(v);

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/tMYSsU)